# Django passing parameters to views and templates

Tags: django, templates, view, parameter-passing

I got a navigation tree that tells me where i am on my website to build that navigation tree i always need to pass all variables from template to the view as `<input type="hidden">`. Then i need to pass it from the view to the next template and it goes on and on feels like a bad solution to pass the variables from every template to every view. so my question is if there is a better solution to my problem here is a screen of the navigation tree.

template:

```
<form action="{% url 'aktentabelle' %}" method="post" style="display:inline-block">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="mitglied" value="{{Container.containernr}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="contpk" value="{{Container.pk}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="projectnr" value="{{projectnr}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="{{Container.status}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="chargepk" value="{{chargepk}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="chargenr" value="{{chargenr}}" />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="anzeigen" />
        </form>
```

so in my templates i always need to pass alot of variables as hidden and in my view i need to convert them back to read them:

views.py:

```
def aktentabelle(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest) 
    container = request.POST['mitglied']
    z = AkteForm
    projectnr = request.POST['projectnr']
    chargepk = request.POST['chargepk']
    chargenr = request.POST['chargenr']
    contpk = request.POST['contpk']
    closecontainerform = CloseContainerForm
    akte_list = Akte.objects.filter(container__containernr=container)
    Anzahl_Akten =Akte.objects.filter(container__containernr=container).count
    status = request.POST['status']
    return render(
       request,
       'app/aktentabelle.html',
       {
        'title':'About',
        'akte_list':akte_list,
        'anzahl':Anzahl_Akten,
        'container':container,
        'aktenform':z,
        'status':status,
        'closecontainerform': closecontainerform,
        'date':datetime.now().date,
        'contpk':contpk,
        'chargepk':chargepk,
        'chargenr':chargenr,
        'projectnr':projectnr,
       }
       )
```

as you can see i use so many lines to just pass all the variables from one template to a view and back to the template again just to build that navigation tree.

Comment: Why not use meaningful urls to identify and track where you are?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/). Something like below.

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

def get_fields(requested_key):
    my_dict={
        'title':'About',
        'akte_list':akte_list,
        'anzahl':Anzahl_Akten,
        'container':container,
        'aktenform':z,
        'status':status,
        'closecontainerform': closecontainerform,
        'date':datetime.now().date,
        'contpk':contpk,
        'chargepk':chargepk,
        'chargenr':chargenr,
        'projectnr':projectnr,
       }
    return mydict.get("requested_key","")

register.filter('get_fields', get_fields)
```

Store this in template tags directory with a filename and in your template load this at the top using

`{% load filename %}`.

Then you can do something like below in your template.

```
{% load templatefilename %}
<form action="{% url 'aktentabelle' %}" method="post" style="display:inline-block">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="mitglied" value="{{get_fields|containernr}}"
</form>
```